# Code-First Fluent API com classes complexas em ASP.NET Core 2.1

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, fluent-api, entity-framework-core

Erro ao realizar o `Add-Migration` quando usado classes de ComplexType.

```
public class Cliente : EntityBase
{
    public Cliente()
    {
        #region Create HashSet Properties Lists Dependences

        Titulares = new HashSet<ClienteCoTitular>();
        CoTitulares = new HashSet<ClienteCoTitular>();
        Representantes = new HashSet<ClienteRepresentante>();
        Representados = new HashSet<ClienteRepresentante>();
        CartoesAdicional = new HashSet<ClienteCartaoAdicional>();
        Cartoes = new HashSet<ClienteCartao>();
        Ofertas = new HashSet<ClienteOferta>();            
        PacotesServicos = new HashSet<ClientePacoteServico>();
        Tarifas = new HashSet<ClienteTarifa>();
        ProdutosLimites = new HashSet<ClienteProdutoLimite>();
        RendasComplementar = new HashSet<ClienteRendaComplementar>();
        ContasTerceiros = new HashSet<ClienteContaTerceiros>();
        SituacoesDadosCadastrais = new HashSet<ClienteSituacaoDadosCadastrais>();
        Etapas = new HashSet<ClienteEtapa>();
        Esteiras = new HashSet<ClienteEsteiraParametros>();
        Enderecos = new HashSet<ClienteEndereco>();
        Respostas = new HashSet<ClienteResposta>();
        Perguntas = new HashSet<ClientePergunta>();            
        RendasComplementar = new HashSet<ClienteRendaComplementar>();
        TokensAcesso = new HashSet<TokenAcesso>();
        ResidenciasFiscalExterior = new HashSet<ClienteResidenciaFiscalExterior>();
        PessoasAutorizadaMovConta = new HashSet<ClientePessoaAutorizadaMovConta>();

        #endregion
    }

    #region Properties 

    public long ClienteId { get; set; }        
    public string NivelVinculoOrganizacaoSafra { get; set; }
    public string NumeroRegistroGerente { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataAberturaConta { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Properties ComplexTypes

    public Filiacao Filiacao { get; set; }
    public Dependentes Dependentes { get; set; }
    public DadosPessoal DadosPessoal { get; set; }
    public Contato Contato { get; set; }
    public Conjugue Conjugue { get; set; }
    public Profissao Profissao { get; set; }
    public ContaCorrente ContaCorrente { get; set; }
    public DocumentosAnexos DocumentosAnexos { get; set; }
    public Renda Renda { get; set; }
    public Patrimonio Patrimonio { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Properties Indicadores S/N

    public bool IndicadorResidenciaFiscalExterior { get; set; }        
    public bool IndicadorPoliticamenteExposta { get; set; }
    public bool IndicadorOperaPorContaDeTerceiros { get; set; }
    public bool IndicadorVinculadaOrganizacaoesSafra { get; set; }                
    public bool IndicadorAutorizaPessoasMovConta { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Properties Relations Foreign Keys

    public long DocumentoId { get; set; }
    public virtual Documento Documento { get; set; }

    #endregion

    #region Properties Enums Identificadores

    public Enums.IdentificadorPAC IdentificadorPAC { get; set; }
    public Enums.IdentificadorConta IdentificadorConta { get; set; }        
    public Enums.IdentificadorGenero IdentificadorGenero { get; set; }        
    public Enums.IdentificadorEstadoCivil IdentificadorEstadoCivil { get; set; }
    public Enums.IdentificadorTitularidade IdentificadorTitularidade { get; set; }
    public Enums.IdentificadorEscolaridade IdentificadorEscolaridade { get; set; }
    public Enums.IdentificadorTipoClienteConta IdentificadorClienteConta { get; set; }
    public Enums.IdentificadorSegmentoCliente IdentificadorSegmentoCliente { get; set; }                
    public Enums.IdentificadorCapacidadeCivil IdentificadorCapacidadeCivil { get; set; }
    public Enums.IdentificadorModalidadeConta IdentificadorModalidadeConta { get; set; }
    public Enums.IdentificadorTipoClienteConta IdentificadorTipoClienteConta { get; set; }        
    public Enums.IdentificadorTitularidadeConta IdentificadorTitularidadeConta { get; set; }        
    public Enums.IdentificadorStatusCadastroCliente IdentificadorStatusCadastro { get; set; }
    public Enums.IdentificadorPropositoNaturezaRelacaoNegocioBanco IdentificadorPropositoNaturezaRelacaoNegocioBanco { get; set; }
    #endregion

    #region Properties Lists Dependences

    public virtual ICollection<ClienteCoTitular> Titulares { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClienteCoTitular> CoTitulares { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClienteRepresentante> Representantes { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<ClienteRepresentante> Representados { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClienteCartaoAdicional> CartoesAdicional { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClienteCartao> Cartoes { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClienteOferta> Ofertas { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClienteTarifa> Tarifas { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClientePacoteServico> PacotesServicos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClienteProdutoLimite> ProdutosLimites { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<ClienteContaTerceiros> ContasTerceiros { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClienteSituacaoDadosCadastrais> SituacoesDadosCadastrais { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClienteEtapa> Etapas { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClienteEsteiraParametros> Esteiras { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClienteEndereco> Enderecos { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClienteResposta> Respostas { get; set; }        
    public virtual ICollection<ClientePergunta> Perguntas { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClienteRendaComplementar> RendasComplementar { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<TokenAcesso> TokensAcesso { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClienteResidenciaFiscalExterior> ResidenciasFiscalExterior { get; set; }
    public virtual ICollection<ClientePessoaAutorizadaMovConta> PessoasAutorizadaMovConta { get; set; }

    #endregion
}
```

> Uma das classes ComplexType usado na classe Cliente

```
[ComplexType]
public class DadosPessoais
{
    public string NumeroCpf { get; set; }
    public string NomeCompleto { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public string LocalNascimento { get; set; }
    public string Nacionalidade { get; set; }
}
```

> Fluent API - Mapping

```
public class ClienteMap : EntityTypeConfigurationBase<Cliente>
{
    public override EntityTypeBuilder<Cliente> Config { get; set; }

    public override void Configure(EntityTypeBuilder<Cliente> builder)
    {
        base.Configure(builder);
    }

    public override void ConfiguraPrimaryKey()
    {
        Config.HasKey(x => x.ClienteId);

        Config.Property(x => x.ClienteId)
            .UseSqlServerIdentityColumn();
    }

    public override void ConfiguraProperties()
    {
        Config.OwnsOne(x => x.DadosPessoal, action =>
        {
            action.Property(p => p.NomeCompleto)
                .HasMaxLength(150)
                .IsRequired();

            action.Property(p => p.NumeroCpf)
                .HasMaxLength(11)
                .IsRequired();

            action.Property(p => p.DataNascimento)
                .HasColumnType("DATE")
                .IsRequired();

            action.Property(p => p.LocalNascimento)
                .HasMaxLength(100);

            action.Property(p => p.Nacionalidade)
                .HasMaxLength(100);                
        });

        Config.OwnsOne(x => x.Contato, action =>
        {
            action.Property(x => x.Celular)
                .HasMaxLength(15)
                .IsRequired();

            action.Property(x => x.Email)
                .HasMaxLength(150);

            action.Property(x => x.TelefoneFixo)
                .HasMaxLength(15);
        });

        Config.OwnsOne(x => x.Filiacao, action =>
        {
            action.Property(x => x.NomeCompletoMae)
                .HasMaxLength(150);

            action.Property(x => x.NomeCompletoPai)
                .HasMaxLength(150);
        });

        Config.OwnsOne(x => x.Conjugue, action =>
        {
            action.Property(x => x.NomeCompleto)
                .HasMaxLength(150);

            action.Property(x => x.NumeroCpf)
                .HasMaxLength(11);
        });

        Config.OwnsOne(x => x.Dependentes, action =>
        {
            action.Property(x => x.IndicadorDependentes)
                .HasConversion(this.ConverterIndicador)
                .HasColumnType(this.TypeChar)
                .HasDefaultValue(false);

            action.Property(x => x.NumeroDependentes)
                .HasDefaultValue(0);
        });

        Config.OwnsOne(x => x.Profissao, action =>
        {
            action.Property(x => x.DescricaoProfissao)
                .HasMaxLength(100);

            action.Property(x => x.NomeEmpresa)
                .HasMaxLength(150);

            action.Property(x => x.CnpjEmpresa)
                .HasMaxLength(14);

            action.Property(x => x.DataAdmissao)
                .HasColumnType("DATE");

            action.Property(x => x.DescricaoCargo)
                .HasMaxLength(100);

            action.Property(x => x.IdentificadorNaturezaOcupacao);
        });

        Config.OwnsOne(x => x.Renda, action =>
        {
            action.Property(x => x.ValorRendaMensal)
                .HasDefaultValue(0);

            action.Property(x => x.IndicadorRendaComprovada)
                .HasDefaultValue(Enums.IndicadorRendaComprovada.Nao);

            action.Property(x => x.IdentificadorOrigemRendaPrincipal)
                .HasDefaultValue(Enums.IdentificadorOrigemRendaPrincipal.Salario);
        });

        Config.OwnsOne(x => x.Patrimonio, action =>
        {
            action.Property(x => x.ValorPatrimonio)
                .HasDefaultValue(0);

            action.Property(x => x.IndicadorPatrimonioComImoveis)
              .HasConversion(this.ConverterIndicador)
              .HasColumnType(this.TypeChar)
              .HasDefaultValue(false);

            action.Property(x => x.PercentualPatrimonioComImoveis)
                .HasDefaultValue(0);
        });

        Config.Property(x => x.IndicadorResidenciaFiscalExterior)
            .HasConversion(this.ConverterIndicador)
            .HasColumnType(this.TypeChar)
            .HasDefaultValue(false);

        Config.Property(x => x.IndicadorPoliticamenteExposta)
            .HasConversion(this.ConverterIndicador)
            .HasColumnType(this.TypeChar)
            .HasDefaultValue(false);

        Config.Property(x => x.IndicadorOperaPorContaDeTerceiros)
            .HasConversion(this.ConverterIndicador)
            .HasColumnType(this.TypeChar)
            .HasDefaultValue(false);

        Config.Property(x => x.IndicadorVinculadaOrganizacaoesSafra)
            .HasConversion(this.ConverterIndicador)
            .HasColumnType(this.TypeChar)
            .HasDefaultValue(false);

        Config.Property(x => x.IndicadorAutorizaPessoasMovConta)
            .HasConversion(this.ConverterIndicador)
            .HasColumnType(this.TypeChar)
            .HasDefaultValue(false);

        Config.Property(x => x.NivelVinculoOrganizacaoSafra)
            .HasMaxLength(100);

        Config.Property(x => x.NumeroRegistroGerente)
            .HasMaxLength(10);

        Config.Property(x => x.DataAberturaConta)
            .HasDefaultValue(DateTime.Now)
            .IsRequired();

        Config.OwnsOne(x => x.ContaCorrente, action =>
        {
            action.Property(x => x.NumeroAgencia);

            action.Property(x => x.NumeroContaCorrente);
        });

        Config.OwnsOne(x => x.DocumentosAnexos, action =>
        {
            action.Property(x => x.ArquivoDocumentoIdentificacao);

            action.Property(x => x.ArquivoDocumentoComprovanteRenda);

            action.Property(x => x.ArquivoDocumentoComprovanteResidencia);
        });

        Config.Property(x => x.IdentificadorGenero)
           .HasConversion(this.ConverterGenero)
           .HasDefaultValue(Enums.IdentificadorGenero.Masculino);

        Config.Property(x => x.IdentificadorStatusCadastro)
            .HasDefaultValue(Enums.IdentificadorStatusCadastroCliente.Pendente)
            .IsRequired();

        Config.Property(x => x.IdentificadorTitularidade)               
           .IsRequired();

        Config.Property(x => x.IdentificadorPAC)
           .HasDefaultValue(Enums.IdentificadorPAC.Pac2250)
           .IsRequired();

        Config.Property(x => x.IdentificadorConta)
           .HasDefaultValue(Enums.IdentificadorConta.ContaCorrente)
           .IsRequired();

        Config.Property(x => x.IdentificadorSegmentoCliente)
           .HasDefaultValue(Enums.IdentificadorSegmentoCliente.Private)
           .IsRequired();

        Config.Property(x => x.IdentificadorEscolaridade)
           .HasDefaultValue(Enums.IdentificadorEscolaridade.SemEscolaridade)
           .IsRequired();

        Config.Property(x => x.IdentificadorCapacidadeCivil)
           .HasDefaultValue(Enums.IdentificadorCapacidadeCivil.Maior)
           .IsRequired();

        Config.Property(x => x.IdentificadorEstadoCivil)
           .HasDefaultValue(Enums.IdentificadorEstadoCivil.Solteiro)
           .IsRequired();

        Config.Property(x => x.IdentificadorTipoClienteConta)
           .HasDefaultValue(Enums.IdentificadorTipoClienteConta.Normal)
           .IsRequired();

        Config.Property(x => x.IdentificadorModalidadeConta)
           .HasDefaultValue(Enums.IdentificadorModalidadeConta.E_MovimentacaoIsolada)
           .IsRequired();

        Config.Property(x => x.IdentificadorTitularidadeConta)
           .HasDefaultValue(Enums.IdentificadorTitularidadeConta.Individual)
           .IsRequired();

        Config.Property(x => x.IdentificadorPropositoNaturezaRelacaoNegocioBanco)
           .HasDefaultValue(Enums.IdentificadorPropositoNaturezaRelacaoNegocioBanco.MovimentacoesFinanceirasOuContratacaoDeServicosEProdutosOuCreditos)
           .IsRequired();
    }

    public override void ConfiguraTable()
    {
        Config.ToTable("Cliente");            
    }

    public override void ConfiguraUniqueKeys()
    {
        //Config.HasAlternateKey(x => new { x.DadosPessoal.NumeroCpf, x.IdentificadorTitularidade });
    }

    public override void ConfigureHasData()
    {
        Config.HasData(
            new Cliente()
            {
                ClienteId = 1,
                NivelVinculoOrganizacaoSafra = "Basico",
                NumeroRegistroGerente = "458250",
                DataAberturaConta = DateTime.Now,
                DadosPessoal = new Entities.Entidades.ComplexType.DadosPessoais()
                {
                    NomeCompleto = "Nicola Bogar Uccio",
                    NumeroCpf = "36975780812",
                    DataNascimento = new DateTime(1988, 08, 24).Date,
                    LocalNascimento = "Guararapes",
                    Nacionalidade = "Brasileiro",
                },
                Contato = new Entities.Entidades.ComplexType.Contato()
                {
                    Email = "nicolabogar@live.com",
                    Celular = "55018996716020",
                    TelefoneFixo = "5501834061203",
                },
                Filiacao = new Entities.Entidades.ComplexType.Filiacao()
                {
                    NomeCompletoMae = "Antonia Bogar",
                    NomeCompletoPai = "Wagner Uccio",
                },
                Dependentes = new Entities.Entidades.ComplexType.Dependentes()
                {
                    IndicadorDependentes = false,
                    NumeroDependentes = 0,
                },
                Profissao = new Entities.Entidades.ComplexType.Profissao()
                {
                    DescricaoProfissao = "Analista de Sistemas",
                    IdentificadorNaturezaOcupacao = Enums.IdentificadorNaturezaOcupacao.FuncionarioEmpresaPrivada,
                    DataAdmissao = new DateTime(2018, 07, 02),
                    NomeEmpresa = "Banco Safra",
                    CnpjEmpresa = "123456789",
                    DescricaoCargo = "Analista de Sistemas",
                },
                Renda = new Entities.Entidades.ComplexType.Renda()
                {
                    ValorRendaMensal = 12000.00,
                    IdentificadorOrigemRendaPrincipal = Enums.IdentificadorOrigemRendaPrincipal.Salario,
                    IndicadorRendaComprovada = Enums.IndicadorRendaComprovada.Sim,
                },
                Patrimonio = new Entities.Entidades.ComplexType.Patrimonio()
                {
                    ValorPatrimonio = 12121121.23,
                    IndicadorPatrimonioComImoveis = false,
                    PercentualPatrimonioComImoveis = 10,
                },
                ContaCorrente = new Entities.Entidades.ComplexType.ContaCorrente()
                {
                    NumeroAgencia = 1425,
                    NumeroContaCorrente = 2020203,
                },
                DocumentoId = 2,
                IndicadorResidenciaFiscalExterior = true,
                IndicadorPoliticamenteExposta = false,
                IndicadorOperaPorContaDeTerceiros = true,
                IndicadorVinculadaOrganizacaoesSafra = false,                    
                IndicadorAutorizaPessoasMovConta = true,
                IdentificadorPropositoNaturezaRelacaoNegocioBanco = Enums.IdentificadorPropositoNaturezaRelacaoNegocioBanco.MovimentacoesFinanceirasOuContratacaoDeServicosEProdutosOuCreditos,
                IdentificadorSegmentoCliente = Enums.IdentificadorSegmentoCliente.Private,
                IdentificadorCapacidadeCivil = Enums.IdentificadorCapacidadeCivil.Maior,
                IdentificadorEstadoCivil = Enums.IdentificadorEstadoCivil.Solteiro,
                IdentificadorEscolaridade = Enums.IdentificadorEscolaridade.Superior,                    
                IdentificadorConta = Enums.IdentificadorConta.ContaCorrente,
                IdentificadorTipoClienteConta = Enums.IdentificadorTipoClienteConta.Normal,
                IdentificadorTitularidadeConta = Enums.IdentificadorTitularidadeConta.Individual,
                IdentificadorModalidadeConta =  Enums.IdentificadorModalidadeConta.E_MovimentacaoIsolada,
                IdentificadorPAC = Enums.IdentificadorPAC.Pac4480,
                IdentificadorStatusCadastro = Enums.IdentificadorStatusCadastroCliente.Pendente,
                IdentificadorTitularidade = Enums.IdentificadorTitularidade.Titular
            },
            new Cliente()
            {
                ClienteId = 1,
                NivelVinculoOrganizacaoSafra = "Basico",
                NumeroRegistroGerente = "458250",
                DataAberturaConta = DateTime.Now,
                DadosPessoal = new Entities.Entidades.ComplexType.DadosPessoais()
                {
                    NomeCompleto = "Corina Bogar Uccio",
                    NumeroCpf = "36975780816",
                    DataNascimento = new DateTime(1988, 02, 03).Date,
                    LocalNascimento = "Guararapes",
                    Nacionalidade = "Brasileiro",
                },
                Contato = new Entities.Entidades.ComplexType.Contato()
                {
                    Email = "corinabogar@live.com",
                    Celular = "55018996716020",
                    TelefoneFixo = "5501834061203",
                },
                Filiacao = new Entities.Entidades.ComplexType.Filiacao()
                {
                    NomeCompletoMae = "Antonia Bogar",
                    NomeCompletoPai = "Wagner Uccio",
                },
                Dependentes = new Entities.Entidades.ComplexType.Dependentes()
                {
                    IndicadorDependentes = false,
                    NumeroDependentes = 0,
                },
                Profissao = new Entities.Entidades.ComplexType.Profissao()
                {
                    DescricaoProfissao = "Analista de Sistemas",
                    IdentificadorNaturezaOcupacao = Enums.IdentificadorNaturezaOcupacao.FuncionarioEmpresaPrivada,
                    DataAdmissao = new DateTime(2018, 07, 02),
                    NomeEmpresa = "Banco Safra",
                    CnpjEmpresa = "123456789",
                    DescricaoCargo = "Analista de Sistemas",
                },
                Renda = new Entities.Entidades.ComplexType.Renda()
                {
                    ValorRendaMensal = 12000.00,
                    IdentificadorOrigemRendaPrincipal = Enums.IdentificadorOrigemRendaPrincipal.Salario,
                    IndicadorRendaComprovada = Enums.IndicadorRendaComprovada.Sim,
                },
                Patrimonio = new Entities.Entidades.ComplexType.Patrimonio()
                {
                    ValorPatrimonio = 12121121.23,
                    IndicadorPatrimonioComImoveis = false,
                    PercentualPatrimonioComImoveis = 10,
                },
                ContaCorrente = new Entities.Entidades.ComplexType.ContaCorrente()
                {
                    NumeroAgencia = 1425,
                    NumeroContaCorrente = 2020203,
                },
                DocumentoId = 1,
                IndicadorResidenciaFiscalExterior = true,
                IndicadorPoliticamenteExposta = false,
                IndicadorOperaPorContaDeTerceiros = true,
                IndicadorVinculadaOrganizacaoesSafra = false,
                IndicadorAutorizaPessoasMovConta = true,
                IdentificadorPropositoNaturezaRelacaoNegocioBanco = Enums.IdentificadorPropositoNaturezaRelacaoNegocioBanco.MovimentacoesFinanceirasOuContratacaoDeServicosEProdutosOuCreditos,
                IdentificadorSegmentoCliente = Enums.IdentificadorSegmentoCliente.Private,
                IdentificadorCapacidadeCivil = Enums.IdentificadorCapacidadeCivil.Maior,
                IdentificadorEstadoCivil = Enums.IdentificadorEstadoCivil.Solteiro,
                IdentificadorEscolaridade = Enums.IdentificadorEscolaridade.Superior,
                IdentificadorConta = Enums.IdentificadorConta.ContaCorrente,
                IdentificadorTipoClienteConta = Enums.IdentificadorTipoClienteConta.Normal,
                IdentificadorTitularidadeConta = Enums.IdentificadorTitularidadeConta.Individual,
                IdentificadorModalidadeConta = Enums.IdentificadorModalidadeConta.E_MovimentacaoIsolada,
                IdentificadorPAC = Enums.IdentificadorPAC.Pac2250,
                IdentificadorStatusCadastro = Enums.IdentificadorStatusCadastroCliente.Pendente,
                IdentificadorTitularidade = Enums.IdentificadorTitularidade.CoTitular
            }
            );
    }

    public override void ConfigureManyToMany()
    {

    }

    public override void ConfigureOneToMany()
    {
        Config.HasOne(x => x.Documento)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.DocumentoId);
    }

    public override void ConfigureOneToOne()
    {

    }

    public override void ConfigureManyToOne()
    {
        Config.HasOne(x => x.Documento)
            .WithMany()
            .HasForeignKey(x => x.DocumentoId)
            .OnDelete(DeleteBehavior.Restrict)
            .IsRequired();            
    }
}
```

> Erro ao realizar o migration: The properties expression 'x => new <>f__AnonymousType6`2(ClienteId = x.ClienteId, NumeroCpf = x.DadosPessoal.NumeroCpf)' is not valid. The expression should represent a simple property access: 't => t.MyProperty'. When specifying multiple properties use an anonymous type: 't => new { t.MyProperty1, t.MyProperty2 }'. Parameter name: propertyAccessExpression

Answer (score 0):

O código fornecido não teve utilidade, mas pelo que a excessão diz, o problema se deve ao fato de você ter especificado nomes no tipo anônimo (`x => new { ClienteId = x.ClienteId, NumeroCpf = x.DadosPessoal.NumeroCpf }`), ao invés de simplesmente ter fornecido as propriedades, sem atribuições (`x => new { x.ClienteId, x.DadosPessoal.NumeroCpf }`)

Answer (score 0):

Resolvi meu problema da seguinte forma:

> Na classe complexa ao invés de usar o `[ComplexType]` usei o `[Owned]`

```
[Owned]
public class DadosPessoais
{        
    public string NumeroCpf { get; set; }
    public string NomeCompleto { get; set; }
    public DateTime DataNascimento { get; set; }
    public string LocalNascimento { get; set; }
    public string Nacionalidade { get; set; }
}
```

> Classe cliente usando a classe decorada com o `[Owned]`

```
public class Cliente
{
    public virtual DadosPessoais DadosPessoais { get; set; }
}
```

> Ao realizar o migration eu estou 'Mocando valores na tabela para realizar testes', nesse caso tenho que usar o `.HasData()`

```
        modelBuilder.OwnsOne(x => x.DadosPessoais, action =>
        {
            action.Property(p => p.NomeCompleto)
                .HasMaxLength(150)
                .IsRequired();

            action.Property(p => p.NumeroCpf)
                .HasMaxLength(11)
                .IsRequired();

            action.Property(p => p.DataNascimento)
                .HasColumnType("DATE")
                .IsRequired();

            action.Property(p => p.LocalNascimento)
                .HasMaxLength(100);

            action.Property(p => p.Nacionalidade)
                .HasMaxLength(100);

            action.HasData(
                    new 
                    {
                        ClienteId = (long)1,
                        NomeCompleto = "Nicola Bogar Uccio",
                        NumeroCpf = "36975780812",
                        DataNascimento = new DateTime(1988, 08, 24).Date,
                        LocalNascimento = "Guararapes",
                        Nacionalidade = "Brasileiro",
                    },
                    new 
                    {
                        ClienteId = (long)2,
                        NomeCompleto = "Corina Bogar Uccio",
                        NumeroCpf = "36975780816",
                        DataNascimento = new DateTime(1988, 02, 03).Date,
                        LocalNascimento = "Guararapes",
                        Nacionalidade = "Brasileiro",
                    }
                );
        });
```

> Estava fazendo dessa forma:

```
   modelBuilder.HasData(
            new Cliente()
            {
                ClienteId = 1,
                DadosPessoais = new Entities.Entidades.ComplexType.DadosPessoais()
                {
                    NumeroCpf = "12345678",
                    DataNascimento = DateTime.Now,
                    LocalNascimento = "Teste",
                    Nacionalidade = "Teste",
                    NomeCompleto = "Teste"
                }
            }
```

> Onde o correto é criar o HasData da classe cliente sem informar as classes complexas, e quando configurar a classe complexa no OwnsOne criar o HasData da classe complexa e vincular o relacionamento da classe cliente na classe complexa, conforme a seguir:

```
modelBuilder.HasData(
     new Cliente()
     {
         ClienteId = 1
     }


Config.OwnsOne(x => x.DadosPessoais, action =>
        {
            action.Property(p => p.NomeCompleto)
                .HasMaxLength(150)
                .IsRequired();

            action.Property(p => p.NumeroCpf)
                .HasMaxLength(11)
                .IsRequired();

            action.Property(p => p.DataNascimento)
                .HasColumnType("DATE")
                .IsRequired();

            action.Property(p => p.LocalNascimento)
                .HasMaxLength(100);

            action.Property(p => p.Nacionalidade)
                .HasMaxLength(100);

            action.HasData(
                    new 
                    {
                        ClienteId = (long)1,
                        NomeCompleto = "Nicola Bogar Uccio",
                        NumeroCpf = "36975780812",
                        DataNascimento = new DateTime(1988, 08, 24).Date,
                        LocalNascimento = "Guararapes",
                        Nacionalidade = "Brasileiro",
                    },
                    new 
                    {
                        ClienteId = (long)2,
                        NomeCompleto = "Corina Bogar Uccio",
                        NumeroCpf = "36975780816",
                        DataNascimento = new DateTime(1988, 02, 03).Date,
                        LocalNascimento = "Guararapes",
                        Nacionalidade = "Brasileiro",
                    }
                );
        });
```